# Error during installation of neoj4 c# driver using Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, nuget

I just started to play around with C# application using the .NET framework.

I'm trying to install from Nuget [the official neo4j driver package for c#](https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/#neo4j-dotnet-driver) but, despite the fact that from the documentation is stated that it should work with any version of .NET language ([here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/get-started/)), I got an incompatibility error from one of its dependencies (**System.Net.NameResolution 4.0.0**)

My application is a **Console Application** and the target framework is **.NET framework 4.5.2**.

In particular the error I get is:

> Could not install package 'System.Net.NameResolution 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain 
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? I think I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your link states that it *works with any .NET language* not that it works with any version of the .NET framework. This package appears to be for dotnet core *only*, so you will need to look into [getting started](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) with that.